# Passing array to a constructor does not work

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I have a class whose constructor accepts an array. Here it is:

```
Sorter::Sorter(int arr[]) : myArray(arr[])
{

}
```

And here is the header:

```
class Sorter
{

protected :
    int* myArray[];

public :
    Sorter(int* arr[]);

public :
    int Bubble();
};
```

And I have called it like this:

```
int ar[] = { 15, 5, 8 };
    Sorting srt(&ar);

    srt.Bubble();
```

But it throws the following error:

```
1>c:\users\..\Sorter.h(12): warning C4200: nonstandard extension used : zero-sized array in struct/union
1>          Cannot generate copy-ctor or copy-assignment operator when UDT contains a zero-sized array
```

I also changed the declaration fro `..(int arr[])` to `..(int* arr[])` but it still does not work.

I have read that the block of memory could not be copied, thus it should be referenced or pass it address, though I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: You can't do that with zero sized arrays, read the error message.

Comment: `int arr[]` is just a slightly misleading syntax that means `int* arr` actually.

Comment: I'd recommend just using `std::array` if possible.

Comment: @shuttle87 can you elaborate more?

Comment: `std::array` is a good drop in replacement for a c-style array because it does what a c-style array does without some of the bad things that happen with arrays. If you need to resize it just go with `std::vector`, if you can use containers like this the boost to productivity and reliability is very large. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/arrays-are-evil.html

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in code you haven't posted, which is probably this:

```
class Sorter {
  int myArray[];
};
```

You should instead do this:

```
class Sorter {
  int* myArray;
  size_t mySize;
};
```